# Bookmark a variable value in Qlik Sense

Tags: expression, bookmarks, qlikview, inputbox, qliksense

Is there a way to bookmark an input box value in Qlik Sense ?. I know there is a way to do this in Qlik View in Document Properties but wondering how do I achieve this in Qlik Sense. Any help appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Well that functionality is not in Qlik Sense. I have fixed that using Sense Mashups but that's not as trivial as using a bookmark.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the Load Script and set your default variable there:

For example:

```
    Set vShowVolumesTwoTier = 1;
    Set vColourCyan = RGB(0,232,232)
```

You could also Save these to a Config file and import this through the Load Script.

Comment: Does this work in Qlik Sense ? I think this is limited to Qlik View.

Comment: No it works according to the Qliksense documentation the same way as it does for Qlikview - have a look at the attached link for a couple examples.

Answer (score -1):

Just find, 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w5dTLv8XU50&t=0s&list=PLkRFvjyuHFvJzisE2CizLezYenmn6DpBz&index=2

For example you can use all vars in one list and change it before or after reload docs... 
but if in script you set another value - it will be overwritten after reload